# Agreement of a verb with its subject when another noun phrase appears between them

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I failed this question in a test but I don't think I was wrong.

Instruction: Choose the correct vèrb from the pair in parenthesis.

3. knowledge of different cultures (helps/help) to survive in a global academy.

I chose help and was marked down and told that 'knowledge is singular as such the verb should be singular as well'.

Could someone shed more light on this?

Comment: I've added an answer. The example sentence is not correct.  It needs to say "Knowledge of different cultures helps "us" to survive" or  "... people to survive" or something like that.

Comment: Also in your title "which of us" is singular so you should write "Which or us was right?"

Comment: @JamesK I suppose the title could be correct if the OP is asking about their class as a whole, in which case there can be multiple people who *were* right. "Which of us" may refer to one or more than one person depending on context, it's not necessarily singular. It would have to be "was" if the OP is referring to themselves and one other person disagreeing, though. You're probably correct since there's no implication of more than two parties, but "which of us were right" isn't necessarily incorrect from the limited context here.

Comment: The title did a very poor job of describing the issue (it actually didn't describe the issue at all), so I edited it.

Comment: BTW, this question is a duplictate of many, many others on ELL. Please try to research your issue (including looking for duplicates) before asking. You may get the answer more quickly, it saves people the effort of reading and answering, it reduces clutter on the site, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In English the verb must "agree" with the subject.

> They play tennis

> He plays tennis.

If the subject is singular  (and not first person "I" or second person "you") the verb has an "s".

The subject "knowledge" is singular.  It is non-count and all non-count nouns are singular.

The subject is not "cultures",  the phrase "of different cultures" modifies the noun "knowledge".  The head word of the subject is singular.

So the verb has an "s"

> Knowledge ... helps ...